# HistoryLevel mismatch on Camunda 7.2

Tags: camunda

I deployed camunda.war (7.2) into my vanilla tomcat7 following the guide on official web-site.

Now when i starting tomcat i have the following error:

```
GRAVE: Error while closing command context
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: historyLevel mismatch: configuration says org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.history.HistoryLevelAudit@21 and database says 3
```

In the database (ACT_GE_PROPERTY table) the historyLevel is set to 3
this is my bpm-platform.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpm-platform xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/BpmPlatform ">

  <job-executor>
    <job-acquisition name="default" />
  </job-executor>

  <process-engine name="default">
    <job-acquisition>default</job-acquisition>
    <configuration>org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration</configuration>
    <datasource>java:jdbc/solve</datasource> 

    <properties>
      <property name="history">full</property>
      <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
      <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
      <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">true</property>
    </properties>


    <plugins>

    <!-- plugin enabling Process Application event listener support -->
        <plugin>
           <class>org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.event.ProcessApplicationEventListenerPlugin</class>
        </plugin>

    <!-- plugin enabling integration of camunda Spin -->
        <plugin>
           <class>org.camunda.spin.plugin.impl.SpinProcessEnginePlugin</class>
        </plugin>

        <!-- plugin enabling connect support -->
        <plugin>
           <class>org.camunda.connect.plugin.impl.ConnectProcessEnginePlugin</class>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </process-engine>

</bpm-platform>
```

**EDIT**

Processes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<process-application 
     xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/ProcessApplication" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 

  <process-archive name="MyProcess"> 
    <process-engine>myEngine</process-engine>
    <properties> 
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">false</property> 
      <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property> 
    </properties> 
  </process-archive> 

</process-application>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">


    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/my_process" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="processEngineName" value="myEngine" /> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:*.bpmn" />
        <property name="processEnginePlugins">
            <list>
              <bean id="spinPlugin" class="org.camunda.spin.plugin.impl.SpinProcessEnginePlugin" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.container.ManagedProcessEngineFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />

    <bean id="MyProcess" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringServletProcessApplication" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="it.processes.Starter" />
    <bean id="cudOnProcessVariableService" class="it.services.CUDonProcessVariableService" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you download the 'camunda standalone webapp' WAR for Tomcat from [camunda.org/download](http://camunda.org/release/camunda-bpm/tomcat/7.2/camunda-webapp-tomcat-standalone-7.2.0.war)?

If so, you should adjust the history level inside the 'application-context.xml' file by adding `<property name="history" value="full"/>` to the process engine configuration bean `<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration>`.

Otherwise it is strange that you write you install `camunda.war` to a vanilla Tomcat but post a reference to your `bpm-platform.xml` file which is not used at all when you are not using the shared process engine approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Hawky4s. 
I downloaded the standalone version from pugins store. 
I solved updating historyLevel to 2 into the database and setting <property name="history">audit</property>. Is it right?

should I remove bpm-platform.xml?

Comment: I tried to remove bpm-platform.xml and i have an error because tomcat try to parse the file

Comment: Okay, so to get the environment straight: I assume you are using the camunda bpm 7.2.0 tomcat distribution from the download site, because you said the Tomcat doesn't start without the bpm-platform.xml. If you use the camunda.war from the distribution and its the first time there shouldn't be any problem. Did you start the shared engine on a previously used database? Maybe you already used the database for a unit test?

Comment: Hi Hawky4s, now i try to restart all configurations (in shared engine mode). And this is the my steps:
1) downloaded tomcat7 from apache website; 2) downloaded and deployed camunda.war (shared engine) from camunda plugins website; 3) downloaded and deployed engine-rest.war. Now all is ok! Now i'm tring to deploy my web application (where i have my processess.xml, and my applicationContext.xml to use spring framework) and i have the error: historyLevel mismatch: configuration says org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.history.HistoryLevelAudit@21 and database says 3

Comment: Could you please post your processes.xml and applicationContext.xml? It looks to me like you are creating an additional process engine using the same datasource as an existing one.

Comment: I edited added the processes.xml and applicationContext.xml files